# Parameter time/date between in reporting services

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I heed to define 2 parameters in reporting services

1. to select date between 2 dates (ideally 2 calendars)
2. to select time; I have 3 needed ranges (08:00:00-15:59:59, 16:00:00-23:59:59, 00:00:00-07:59:59) Ideally 3 buttons.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use three parameters:

1. FromDate with prompt of "From:", DateTime type.
2. ToDate with prompt of "to:" DateTime type.
3. TimeRange with prompt "Times:" Int type with three hardcoded options:

Possible value for TimeRange:

```
Value  Label
1      0 - 8
2      8 - 16
3      16 - 0
```

Note that you can set the labels to whatever will help your users: "Early shift (Midnight - 8AM)"

Then in your SQL hand in the TimeRange parameter as an int and convert it to two parameters for your SQL.

```
DECLARE @StartHour INT
DECLARE @EndHour INT

SET @StartHour = CASE @TimeRange WHEN 1 THEN 0
                                 WHEN 2 THEN 8
                                 WHEN 3 THEN 16
                 END

SET @EndHour = CASE @TimeRange   WHEN 1 THEN 8
                                 WHEN 2 THEN 16
                                 WHEN 3 THEN 24
                 END


SELECT
   *
FROM
   LogEntries
WHERE
   LogEntries.TimeOfEntry >= @FromDate
   AND LogEntries.TimeOfEntry < @ToDate
   AND DATEPART( hh , LogEntries.TimeOfEntry ) >= @StartHour
   AND DATEPART( hh , LogEntries.TimeOfEntry ) < @EndHour
```

(Don't use BETWEEN if you are using my exact code, it won't handle the EndHour appropriately.)